# Unable to access Camera + Images on NEST API

Tags: nest-api

I've registered an app on the developers portal, but I'm unable to access the "Camera + images".
I've read on the documentation and seems like you need to have Nest Aware subscription, which I have (trial) and I plan to continue to use it after the trial.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the Camera permission to select "Camera + images".  There is a lot of overlap on the various camera permissions, but only one of the 4 options is selectable at a time.